# how to assign to php variable single value from last row in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the value from last row in SQL and then assign it to php variable

```
<?php
    $get_last_record = "SELECT code FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
?>
```

So I already got those last row with only value called "code" now how i should assign it to variable ?

Comment: You have to run the SQL and take the value from the result set.

Comment: I don't have any ideas how to exactly do that

Comment: [Then this is where you should start](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php
    $get_last_record = "SELECT code FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result_query = mysqli_query($reference_to_your_mysqli_connect,    $get_last_record);
    $data_from_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query);
    $code = $data_from_query['code'];
    echo $code;
?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
Hope following is what you are trying, I have a db named "prod" and table named "products" with a column named "code"

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "prod";
try
{
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$sql = "SELECT code from products order by id desc LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$codevar = $row['code'];
echo $codevar;
```

?>